# How to add/change Workfusion OCR Configuration without reinstalling it Or resolve OCR issue

Tags: workfusion

Open Workfusion Studio.

Select Bottom Right corner 
**Server Profile : Default**

Choose **Manage profile** on clicking on it.

In Preference window
Select **WorkFusion studio -> Server Profiles** Side menu

In this configuration what is the value of below fields.
**OCR**
Instance ?
JWT Issuer ?
JWT Secret ?

Actually I got below error when i run OCR with my workfusion studio
[image]Error executing OcrAction
  com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.PlaybackException: Error executing TemplateAction[templateName=OcrAction.ftl,id=2,name=Optional[OcrAction],parent=-1,nextSibling=3,arguments=ActionArguments[varName=[name],imageName=[C:\Users\Administrator\workfusion-workspace\rpae_project\OCR\1532498224608-anchor-1532498224737.apng],fullImageName=[1532498224608.png],xsi:type=[recorder:OcrAction, recorder:OcrAction],pollingInterval=[300],active=[true],type=[CONTROL],offsetX=[-353],delay=[5000],offsetY=[272],width=[156],actionDetails=[(to 'name' rectangle 156 x 26)],height=[26],awaitTimeout=[5000]]]
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.flow.StandardControlFlow.execute(StandardControlFlow.java:54)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.action.template.TemplateAction.execute(TemplateAction.java:30)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.action.template.TemplateAction.execute(TemplateAction.java:17)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.player.ActionPlayer.next(ActionPlayer.java:53)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.player.PlaybackLogic.playNextAction(PlaybackLogic.java:153)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.player.PlaybackLogic.run(PlaybackLogic.java:113)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to execute script. URI is not absolute
Build info: version: '9.0.0.3', revision: '1610cb545e', time: '2018-05-24T16:45:36.185Z'
System info: host: 'WIN-NC78EG9TDCU', ip: '192.168.192.133', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: UniversalDriver
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:41)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:82)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:656)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:592)
      at com.workfusion.rpa.helpers.RPA.executeScript(RPA.java:864)
      at com.workfusion.rpa.helpers.RPA.executeGroovyScript(RPA.java:930)
      at com.workfusion.rpa.helpers.Ocr.proccessImage(Ocr.java:111)
      at com.workfusion.rpa.helpers.Ocr.proccessImage(Ocr.java:35)
      at com.workfusion.rpa.helpers.Ocr$proccessImage.call(Unknown Source)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
      at Script2.run(Script2.groovy:7)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.shell.GroovyShellWrapper.executeScript(GroovyShellWrapper.java:90)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.player.PlaybackContext.executeScript(PlaybackContext.java:65)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.action.template.TemplateAction.executeBehavior(TemplateAction.java:35)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.flow.StandardControlFlow.execute(StandardControlFlow.java:46)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.action.template.TemplateAction.execute(TemplateAction.java:30)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.action.template.TemplateAction.execute(TemplateAction.java:17)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.player.ActionPlayer.next(ActionPlayer.java:53)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.player.PlaybackLogic.playNextAction(PlaybackLogic.java:153)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.player.PlaybackLogic.run(PlaybackLogic.java:113)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to execute script. URI is not absolute
Build info: version: '9.0.0.3', revision: '1610cb545e', time: '2018-05-24T16:45:36.185Z'
System info: host: 'WIN-NC78EG9TDCU', ip: '192.168.192.133', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: UniversalDriver
Build info: version: '9.0.0.3', revision: '1610cb545e', time: '2018-05-24T16:45:36.185Z'
System info: host: 'WIN-NC78EG9TDCU', ip: '192.168.192.133', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: UniversalDriver
      at com.workfusion.autoit.driver.AutoItDriver.executeScript(AutoItDriver.java:189)
      at com.workfusion.universal.driver.UniversalDriver.executeScript(UniversalDriver.java:149)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ExecuteScript.call(ExecuteScript.java:54)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.WebDriverHandler.handle(WebDriverHandler.java:41)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:133)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:203)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.InMemorySession.execute(InMemorySession.java:98)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.lambda$handle$0(WebDriverServlet.java:231)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Issue resolved by community

Comment: please share the resolution with community. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Resolved By => https://forum.workfusion.com/t/ocr-error-in-rpa-express-2-0/37091/21

Answer (score 0):

If RPA Express is installed on single machine (both server + workstation installation on same system) then enter below details:

Instance : http://localhost:15580/api

JWT Issuer : enter username (provided during installation, check below screen to remind)

JWT Secret : enter password (provided during installation)

[image]

If OCR server is different then change the Instance URL accordingly.