# Error executing OCR

Tags: workfusion

Error executing OcrAction
  com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.PlaybackException: Error executing TemplateAction[templateName=OcrAction.ftl,id=2,name=Optional[OcrAction],parent=-1,nextSibling=3,arguments=ActionArguments[varName=[name],imageName=[C:\Users\Administrator\workfusion-workspace\rpae_project\OCR\1532498224608-anchor-1532498224737.apng],fullImageName=[1532498224608.png],xsi:type=[recorder:OcrAction, recorder:OcrAction],pollingInterval=[300],active=[true],type=[CONTROL],offsetX=[-353],delay=[5000],offsetY=[272],width=[156],actionDetails=[(to 'name' rectangle 156 x 26)],height=[26],awaitTimeout=[5000]]]
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.flow.StandardControlFlow.execute(StandardControlFlow.java:54)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.action.template.TemplateAction.execute(TemplateAction.java:30)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.action.template.TemplateAction.execute(TemplateAction.java:17)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.player.ActionPlayer.next(ActionPlayer.java:53)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.player.PlaybackLogic.playNextAction(PlaybackLogic.java:153)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.player.PlaybackLogic.run(PlaybackLogic.java:113)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  **Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.workfusion.desktop.driver.ocr.impl.OcrException cannot be found by com.workfusion.studio.dependencies.rpa-api_9.0.0.3**
Build info: version: '9.0.0.3', revision: '1610cb545e', time: '2018-05-24T16:45:36.185Z'
System info: host: 'WIN-NC78EG9TDCU', ip: '192.168.192.133', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.CustomWrapper.isCustomWrapperElement(CustomWrapper.java:44)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:218)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convertMap(JsonToBeanConverter.java:351)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:228)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:48)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:149)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:48)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:82)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:656)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:592)
      at com.workfusion.rpa.helpers.RPA.executeScript(RPA.java:864)
      at com.workfusion.rpa.helpers.RPA.executeGroovyScript(RPA.java:930)
      at com.workfusion.rpa.helpers.Ocr.proccessImage(Ocr.java:111)
      at com.workfusion.rpa.helpers.Ocr.proccessImage(Ocr.java:35)
      at com.workfusion.rpa.helpers.Ocr$proccessImage.call(Unknown Source)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
      at Script2.run(Script2.groovy:7)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.shell.GroovyShellWrapper.executeScript(GroovyShellWrapper.java:90)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.player.PlaybackContext.executeScript(PlaybackContext.java:65)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.action.template.TemplateAction.executeBehavior(TemplateAction.java:35)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.flow.StandardControlFlow.execute(StandardControlFlow.java:46)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.action.template.TemplateAction.execute(TemplateAction.java:30)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.action.template.TemplateAction.execute(TemplateAction.java:17)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.player.ActionPlayer.next(ActionPlayer.java:53)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.player.PlaybackLogic.playNextAction(PlaybackLogic.java:153)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.player.PlaybackLogic.run(PlaybackLogic.java:113)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.workfusion.desktop.driver.ocr.impl.OcrException cannot be found by com.workfusion.studio.dependencies.rpa-api_9.0.0.3
      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
      at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.CustomWrapper.isCustomWrapperElement(CustomWrapper.java:42)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:218)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convertMap(JsonToBeanConverter.java:351)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:228)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:48)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:149)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:48)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:82)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:656)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:592)
      at com.workfusion.rpa.helpers.RPA.executeScript(RPA.java:864)
      at com.workfusion.rpa.helpers.RPA.executeGroovyScript(RPA.java:930)
      at com.workfusion.rpa.helpers.Ocr.proccessImage(Ocr.java:111)
      at com.workfusion.rpa.helpers.Ocr.proccessImage(Ocr.java:35)
      at com.workfusion.rpa.helpers.Ocr$proccessImage.call(Unknown Source)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
      at Script2.run(Script2.groovy:7)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.shell.GroovyShellWrapper.executeScript(GroovyShellWrapper.java:90)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.player.PlaybackContext.executeScript(PlaybackContext.java:65)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.action.template.TemplateAction.executeBehavior(TemplateAction.java:35)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.flow.StandardControlFlow.execute(StandardControlFlow.java:46)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.action.template.TemplateAction.execute(TemplateAction.java:30)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.action.template.TemplateAction.execute(TemplateAction.java:17)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.playback.player.ActionPlayer.next(ActionPlayer.java:53)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.player.PlaybackLogic.playNextAction(PlaybackLogic.java:153)
      at com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.player.PlaybackLogic.run(PlaybackLogic.java:113)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add/change Workfusion OCR Configuration without reinstalling it Or resolve OCR issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51513262/how-to-add-change-workfusion-ocr-configuration-without-reinstalling-it-or-resolv)

Comment: Its a versioning issue. I upgrade my workfusion studio from 2.0.1 to 2.0.4 and its working perfectly. Or you can specify server profile configuration with it.